# Chrome >=24 - how to dock devtools to the right?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I like docking devtools to the right. I remember how happy I was when I first saw that option when I realized I no longer have to split screen and position windows manually.

Recent versions of chrome that option seems to be missing. Even on my installs where I already have devtools on the right the option is removed.

Where did it go?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reposition chrome developer tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023640/how-to-reposition-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: @ndsmyter not really. The positioning controls changed with version 24. Much of the advice in that thread is likely outdated.

Comment: And still, the question and answers are exactly the same as in this thread

Answer (score 262, accepted):

If you click and hold on the icon in the top right next to the close icon (Undock into separate window button), you are given the option to dock it to the right. See screenshot:

[image: Dock to right]

Starting in Chrome 41, you are able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Mac OS X) to be able to toggle between these views.

Starting in Chrome 46, they've finally changed the user interface for the docking location. There's a vertical ellipsis now and in there it has explicit buttons for each docking location. See screenshot:

[image: New Docking]

Comment: Not very intuitive place to put the option. Why not side-by-side like:
[dock/undoc][bottom/right][console][select]?

Comment: @Byran I think that's where it used to be actually. :)

Comment: This is also the way to see the option to dock the devtool to a new window... so thanks!

Comment: A click to open options and one to dock would be more intuitive.

Comment: Click and hold is not intuitive when it has a down arrow suggesting a menu. Thanks for showing the way.

Comment: They changed the design slightly (the button is at the top-right part of the dev tools window), but this still works! Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you. I tried all combinations (shift, ctrl, cmd, alt), but not "hold".

Comment: Thanks Marc! this is the answer I was looking for ... works in Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111

Comment: note to people thinking about copying this terrible design: please no! :)

Comment: The "Dock side" menu item is not available to me.  Seems to have something to do with a custom window having menu removed.