# How do I set the default position for chrome developer tools in incognito

Tags: google-chrome, incognito-mode

When I open an new incognito window and open the developer tools its always docked to the bottom :S

Is there any way I can set the default dock to the right? Or is there some hotkey I can use to change the dock position?

Comment: Agreed, this is so annoying. I want the other way around though, so I somehow managed to get it stuck on the right and have to re-dock it to the bottom every time.

Comment: There seems to be [heated debate](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376788) about whether or not incognito should remember DevTools settings. In the meantime, does anyone know of an extension that can remember the settings for those of us who want it?

Answer (score 11):

The chromium ticket today was marked as won't fix https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376788

So it is very unlikely we will get this behavior.  Personally I hate the default behavior being dock to right.

The original argument for it being changed to dock to right was because lots of people were upvoting these questions about how to dock it to right.

- [Chrome >=24 - how to dock devtools to the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386994/chrome-24-how-to-dock-devtools-to-the-right)
- [How to reposition chrome developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023640/how-to-reposition-chrome-developer-tools)

Maybe if we get enough people to upvote how to make it go back to the bottom they will change it back :)

**EDIT**: On second thought it looks like it is now picking up some traction, and they are working on implementing this.  See comment https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376788#c45

**EDIT #2**: Chrome 44 was just released and now the position is carried over when you open a new incognito window

Comment: Docking to the right is terrible default behavior in my opinion. I have voted on the ticket to maybe get it some more attention.

Comment: Rejoice!  Looks like this is now implemented.

Answer (score 0):

When the dev tools open right next to the `x` to close them you see the option to undock it and open it in a separate window... if you click and hold it, it will show you an option to dock it in the right panel.

Also, as a note... this is not specific to incognito.

Comment: This only docks right for the current session. If I close the incognito window and re-open it the tools will reset and dock to the bottom. I'm looking for a way to set the default dock position

Comment: @TimothyAhong right because you are incognito. If you do it outside of incognito then it will set it as the default. If you read the box as soon as you open up incognito you will know why :  `You've gone incognito. Pages you view in incognito tabs won't stick around in your browser's history, cookie store, or search history after you've closed all of your incognito tabs. `

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a setting in the inspector settings (you can open them by pressing "?" while the inspector is open), but it was removed in favor of "position priorities", these being:

1. Right Dock
2. Bottom Dock
3. Undock

If you change its position it is persistent as long as you have a session, this means the position won't be remembered in incognito.

EDIT: Also, you can long-press the dock selection button (top right corner of the inspector) to select directly an option.

[Discussion about it.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408242)