# Undock Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How do I undock the Chrome Developer Tools in Chrome?
Pressing the left bottom corner just moves it to the right side.

[image: Chrome Corner]
<sub>(source: [github.io](http://jeremistadler.github.io/corner.png))</sub>

Comment: the similar question was asked here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023640/how-to-reposition-chrome-developer-tools?rq=1

Answer (score 385, accepted):

Click the vertical ellipsis button ( ⋮ ) then choose the desired docking option. (the docking option with the red circle around it, is undock)

[image]

For older version of Chrome, press and hold the corner button

[image]

You can also undock/dock-to-left/dock-to-right/dock-to-bottom from the Command Menu. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Windows, Linux, Chrome OS) to open the Command Menu, then start typing `bottom`/`left`/`right`/`undock`.

[image: undocking via command menu]

DevTools documentation on docking: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ui#placement

Comment: No way to figure it out without hint, terrible UX.

Comment: Was just about to halve my keyboard over my knee, so ta.

Comment: What corner? Without your image (blocked by firewall) it took me over a minute to figure out what I should be clicking.

Comment: That UX design is idiotic: you choose the "non-docking" docking option. Hail to thee, designer. :-(

Comment: I'd like to get the console separately showing on my second screen, while the rest of DevTools stays docked in my main window. I found no way to accomplish this. Anyone?

Answer (score 24):

**shortcut key for toggle dock side**

<kbd>**ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**shift**</kbd>+<kbd>**D**</kbd>

and there are many shortcuts you can see them
go to
**settings->shortcuts**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look for the "***three-dot icon***" at the corner of the **`developer tool panel`**, then you can find the toggle dock button.