# Inspect element without right clicking in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, inspect

When I inspect html/css on a website, I usually open the chrome developers panel  <kbd>ctrl+shift+I</kbd>  → right click context menu "inspect" so I can highlight that class

however, sometimes I'm trying to inspect an element that is sensitive to "right clicks" events , e.g. if I right click an item on the website functionality changes

Example: 
[image]

so I can't inspect an element

Normally I inspect elements like this (e.g. stackoverflow)

[image]

How do you inspect an element without using the right click button?

Normally I would have to just dig through the chrome developer's panel elements and just go one by one to find said element, which takes a really long time

I must be missing something important here about chrome's inspect element tools.
Could someone enlighten me here a better workflow / maybe chrome extension tools?

Comment: ah okay the ctrl+shift+C method works really well here. http://i.imgur.com/qJ5maMM.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try pressing `ctrl+shift+c`. This will open the dev tools in element selection mode, allowing you to left-click on elements to jump straight to them in the elements view.

Comment: On a Mac press `command` + `shift` + `c` for the same Chrome feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to enter a mode where you can mouse over elements and it will inspect it. With your mouse over the element you want to inspect, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again and your element will be selected in the developer panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the dev tools on a different windows and refresh your page or use [firebug](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench/https%3A//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elkkomimknapgodalnkjeddkjnjkfmfp).

or use Firefox

Comment: what do you mean by opening dev tools on a different window though? i thought the devtools has to be on the same page as what your inspecting?

Comment: no, you can undock it to separate window. open it, click on the 3 dots next to the closing cross on the top right of the dev tools, and undock it. 

explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220090/undock-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: is each window equivalent to one website you are viewing? (when docked)

Comment: it's linked to the one you are inspecting