# Adjust the dock position of Chrome DevTools on the remote debugging window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

According to the official [instructions](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) using `Chrome DevTools` from the host browser to debug the connected mobile device, I see that the remote debugging window opens, where the layout is by default vertically split, i.e. the `screencast` of Chrome mobile browser appears on the left while the `DevTools` instance on the right.

I know that we can adjust the [dock position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10035408/363663) of `DevTools` on the host browser. How can we achieve this similarly to split the remote debugging window horizontally, docking the `screencast` on the top and the `DevTools` on the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't currently possible.

Outstanding feature request: https://crbug.com/620427

The more stars the request gets, the more likely the team is to implement the feature.