# How to dock Chrome DevTools debugger at the bottom of the DevTools panel

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Currently, when I drag devTools to the left to make it bigger, my debugger jumps from the bottom of devTools to the right.
[image]

Is there a way to dock debugger again to the bottom of the DevTools panel? I can make the debugger manually narrower, but it is not what I want.

EDIT:
Ok. I've found a solution by myself. In devTools preferences I had to set Panel layout as horizontal and now it works :)
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reposition Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023640/how-to-reposition-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: No it's not. I don't want to dock whole devTools to the right or to the bottom. I want to dock only debugger part of source panel to the bottom of source panel

Comment: There's no way.