# ngTouch's ngClick prevents checkboxes and videos from working in most mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am currently trying out `ngTouch`'s `ng-click` directive in my application and it seems to break some basic functionality in most mobile devices, (Android / iOS). The checkbox and videos that are wrapped in an html element that has an `ng-click` directive does not work when `ngTouch` is included as a dependency.

The plunker is **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3djXABkWH5HiZu6j9z2A?p=preview)**. As for viewing the problem, you can use **[Google Chrome's Emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182755/where-is-the-new-emulation-tab-in-chromes-console-drawer)** functionality to emulate the problem, I advise viewing it on **[plunker's embededd view](http://embed.plnkr.co/3djXABkWH5HiZu6j9z2A/)**.

Consider this markup when `ngTouch` is included as a dependency on mobile devices:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController"  ng-click="doSomethingAwesome()">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk-1">
  <label for="chk-1">This checkbox and video does not work</label>

  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

You have to click the video or checkbox a couple times(sometimes a lot more) just to mark the checkbox check or to play the video. Removing the `ng-click` directive or removing the `ngTouch` dependency in the application however, solves the problem, but I want to use `ngTouch` directives and services as well.

If anyone could explain this to me or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating another directive that is similar to the original `ngClick`directive, and use that on the parent element, instead of using `ngClick`.

**[UPDATED PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/QJvoMKlKxvgtb6ertlUe?p=preview)**

*DIRECTIVE*

```
.directive('basicClick', function($parse, $rootScope) {
  return {
    compile: function(elem, attr) {
      var fn = $parse(attr.basicClick);
      return function(scope, elem) {
        elem.on('click', function(e) {
          fn(scope, {$event: e});
          scope.$apply();
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```