# Removing the Opera Browser limit on window width

Tags: settings, opera

When doing responsive web design, I'll often manually resize my browser's window. Opera (version 20) will not allow me to resize the browser's window smaller than 498px.  Is there some super secret setting somewhere that will take that will remove that minimum window width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera Presto (up to 12.x) will happily let you resize your window until the viewable area is pretty much gone, same as FF and IE. Version 15+ is based on Blink (forked from WebKit), so you're getting the same behaviour as Chrome, which also forces an artificial minimum window width and height (like most desktop apps).

So it might not be obvious, but your question could potentially be considered a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681903/browser-doesnt-scale-below-400px), though I suppose someone searching for an answer specifically for Opera may not realise that the same applies to both Blink browsers. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11967837/983430) suggests some handy workarounds, and, since Opera Blink uses the same inspector as Chrome (though I still prefer Dragonfly), emulating mobile browsers and screensizes is also possible.

Comment: Chrome lets me resize smaller than opera.  But am I understanding you're answer correctly in that There are only hacky work arounds for free resizing of Opera 20 that I have to implement every time I open Opera?

Comment: I wouldn't call them "hacky", but for now, yes. As the accepted answer to the question I linked to suggests, removing/disabling add-ons can affect the size, but if you want to test widths smaller than 500px, I'd suggest emulating mobile devices anyway. (Read some of the other answers there for workarounds as well.)