# Centering a div in middle of page on resize of page

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to get a div to center in the middle of my page. I get it centering in the middle but I am having a problem when I resize the page. When I make the window as small in width as I can, the div goes off the left of the page. Here is a jsfiddle representing what I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/ghsxnsqy/

Here is some css:

```
.wrapper{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:200px;
    height:60px;
    margin-top: -30px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -100px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Now if you look at that and resize the window to make it as small as you can in width, you can see the div going off to the left. How do I make it stop at the edge of the page? I can't find a way without using margin auto. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which browser are you using as it seems to work fine here. I am using Firefox.

Comment: it works fine on mine. i dont see the error..

Comment: I have checked in Firefox, Chrome and IE 11 as well. I works fine on all of these browsers.

Comment: When you resize the width of the window to the smallest, half the div doesn't keep going to the left with it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
margin-left: -100px;
margin-top: -30px;
```

And apply `transform: translate(-50%);` to `wrapper` class.

`-webkit-transform: translate(-50%);` for webkit browser like chrome.

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghsxnsqy/2/)**

Comment: When I do this I still goes past the left side of the screen. I want it to stop once it hits the left part of the screen. Sorry if I wasn't clear. I tried on firefox and chrome on two different monitors and it didn't work.

Comment: apply webkit for browser like chrome. Check fiddle

Comment: That didn't work either. Maybe something is just wrong with me. So if you added a long string in that div, none would get cut off because it moved left past the screen size?

Comment: don't make screen less than `200px` otherwise it doesn't warp.

Comment: @user081608 You have given fixed width and height. you want like: https://jsfiddle.net/ghsxnsqy/3/ ?

Comment: That doesn't go off the page for me but I didn't want it to warp. Is there a way to check if the distance from the left of the page is zero then make it stop?

Comment: So, you want to restrict window to resize? Chrome can not resize below `400px` width. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681903/browser-doesnt-scale-below-400px. Otherwise there is no solution for it.

Comment: Or try to set `min-width` of body.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set a few CSS properties.`margin: auto;
width: ;`set the width to your desired width/percent. It will automatically make the margin on the left and right side equivalent.

Comment: Yes I've tried that before but when you have something like the developers panel pop up on the bottom of the page, it moves up and down. I want it to stay fixed even if a panel were to pop up.

Comment: @user081608 not sure if there is a way, but I added a Css property to my background that kept it the same position even while scrolling. Background-attachment: fixed;

Answer (score 0):

So I suppose you want either [this push-to-right-instead solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ghsxnsqy/4/) or [this resize-instead solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ghsxnsqy/6/).

Both involve wrapping your actual element inside a container:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">

  </div>
</div>
```

And centering horizontally using text-align:

```
.container{
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -30px;
    position:fixed;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper{
  ...
  display: inline-block;
}
```