# Google Chrome window resizing limitation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, magento2, codeception

We have an open bug in our Automation Testing Framework regarding the resizing limitations of a Chrome Window when it is controlled by Selenium + ChromeDriver and I need help since I can't track down an official answer. As far as I am aware this was not an issue in the past.

We currently use the framework Codeception as the base for our own framework and when we use the action `resizeWindow` with the dimensions `320x568` it resizes the window to `445x500`. Has anyone else ran into this issue with Chrome? It looks like a hardcoded limit at this point. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Below I've provided a few Tests that I've ran looking for the upper and lower limits of the resizing action.

**Test #1**

- Requested Size: 320x568
- Resulting Size: 445x500

**Test #2**

- Requested Size: 5000x5000
- Resulting Size: 858x5000

**Test 3**

- Requested Size: 1x1
- Resulting Size: 252x500

**LINKS**

- [Codeception](https://codeception.com/)
- [Codeception - resizeWindow](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#resizeWindow)
- [Magento Functional Testing Framework](https://github.com/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework)

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to my question in another StackOverflow question.

"Chrome cannot resize horizontally below 400px (OS X) or 218px (Windows)"

[Browser doesn't scale below 400px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681903/browser-doesnt-scale-below-400px?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with selenium dimension import

Import :   import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;

code :

```
    Dimension d = new Dimension(320,568);

    driver.manage().window().setSize(d); //Resize current window to the set dimension
```

Comment: I tried your recommendation but the result was the same. 

Request: 320x568, Result: 445x500

Answer (score 0):

Try using firefox. It works great. since chrome's setting changed and it won't work for testing media queries unless you use the dev tools.