# Chrome doesn't scale below x 500px

Tags: google-chrome, scale

So chrome doesn't scale bellow 500px on x axis. 
Is there a solution ? How will i go about developing responsive design now?

Switching into chrome development mode is a hassle and a waste of time. Just moving the side of the window with pixels showing would be the best.

Answer (score 2):

copy and paste

`javascript:(function(){window.open(document.URL, '','width=320,height=480');})();`

into the console window of the developer window and it will open the page you are viewing in a new window sized to 320x480, it can then be scaled up and down from there, it still has a minimum but it will be far below 500px. I know you said that its a pain to open the window, but you'll only have to do it once and not leave it open for the duration of development.

duplicate of [Browser doesn't scale below 400px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681903/browser-doesnt-scale-below-400px)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've saw other solutions but they are not comfortable to work with, still adds a bit of overhead(new windows, can't change url, etc.). Was hoping that someone come up with something better since it seems as a problem that should affect a large amount of developers.

Answer (score 0):

vscode to the right, browser window to the left, press f12, booommmm, you can resize to any size now :D